# R and ggplot2: show boundaries for aggregations of areas

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, shapefile

My province is diveded into twelve districts and every district is divided in municipalities.
I have to map some health data by district, but my shapefile "knows" only municipalities. So I merged my health data with the data in the shapefile and I mapped the same value for all the municipalities of the same district.
The result is:

[image: Map]

And this is the code:

```
ggplot(df) + 
    aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = COLOR) + 
    geom_polygon() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = palette) +
    geom_path(color=NA) +
    coord_equal() +
    theme_opts
```

As you can see, I removed the **municipality boundaries**, but I have to add **district boundaries**, because there are adjacent districts mapped with the same color, but the user can't distinguish them. Do you have any suggestion?

These are the data to plot:

```
district;COLOR
101;-1
102;0
103;1
104;-1
105;0
106;1
109;-1
110;0
111;1
112;-1
113;0
114;1
```

and this is an extraction of the data in the shapefile (the last two columns are the result of the merge; the municipality id is COD_ISTAT):

```
long;lat;order;hole;piece;id;group;COD_ISTAT;OBJECTID;COD_REG;COD_PRO;PRO_COM;NOME;SHAPE_Leng;SHAPE_Area;district;COLOR
1158442.63774317;4556057.85829892;1;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158509.6371677;4556058.35816913;2;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158571.63687283;4556185.35695679;3;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158659.63610077;4556177.356861;4;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158679.38614406;4556290.85584435;5;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158672.88632394;4556356.85528688;6;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158575.13715917;4556353.85549587;7;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158567.38710377;4556288.85607141;8;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158523.63747073;4556283.8561965;9;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
1158442.63774317;4556057.85829892;10;FALSE;1;6445;6445.1;16072001;6608;16;72;72001;Acquaviva delle Fonti;108308.860715;132026431.639;105;0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide your data, so that we can try it. However, I think you only have to use the fill parameter for district and the color parameter for municipalities if you have a column for each in your original spatial dataset.

Comment: You're right. I edited the question and added data.

Comment: Have you tried `colour=COD_ISTAT` in `aes` ?